# Hello, i have a vb.net application with sql database i want to search the database and filter the search using a comboBox and textBox

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;user id=root; password=; database=ugibl;")
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = Nothing

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim SQL As String = ""
        Try
            **SQL = "select * FROM duty where '" & ComboBox3.Text & "' = '" & TextBox15.Text & "' "**
            con.Open()
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, con)
            da.Fill(dt)
            con.Close()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Subere
```

Answer (score 0):

The character to use in MySql around column names is the backtick (<kbd>ALT+096</kbd>)not the single quote. So your line that creates the sql command is wrong.

```
SQL = "select * FROM duty where `" & ComboBox3.Text & "` = ....
```

However remember that you shouldn't build sql commands concatenating strings but using parameters. In your case the parameter should be used to express the value in your where statement

```
...
SQL = "select * FROM duty where `" & ComboBox3.Text & "` = @param1"
con.Open()
da = New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, con)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  TextBox15.Text
da.Fill(dt)
....
```

Notice that you cannot use a parameter for a column name, you could use them only for values

Comment: If the where is a column why do you even need to enclose it in " ` " ?

Comment: Not sure about the column name. If it contains spaces or is a reserved keyword  then the backticks are needed.